# Play + specs2 + scalacheck?

Tags: scala, playframework, specs2, scalacheck

I can't seem to figure out how to integrate the three. I've found how to test using `specs2` and `scalacheck` like the following:

```
class ExampleSpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is = s2"""
   Example
    scalacheck $e1
  """
  def e1 = prop((i: Int) => i == i)
}
```

using the so-called [`Acceptance specification` style](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#acceptance-specification).

However, with `Play`, [`Unit specification` style](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#unit-specification) is mandatory to make use of goodies like `WithApplication` and whatnot.

I naively thought this would work:

```
class PlayExampleSpec extends PlaySpecification with ScalaCheck {
  "Play" in new WithApplication() {
    "scalacheck" in prop((s: String) => s == s)
  }
}
```

The test doesn't get executed at all. I've looked through half the internet to no avail. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `WithApplication` you need to be able to throw exceptions when a property fails (because `prop` is pure and will get lost in the body of `WithApplication`). `AsResult` does this for you:

```
import org.specs2.execute.AsResult

class TestMutableSpec extends mutable.Specification with ScalaCheck {
  "Example" in new WithApplication { 
    AsResult {
      prop((s: String) => s != s)
    }
  }
}
```

The example above should fail.

Comment: You are right. It indeed works. Yet, what doesn't work is when you put that block inside `WithApplication` from `Play`. I've edited the question if you can help, I'll be forever grateful.

Comment: That's it! It's unfortunate that this isn't too well documented. Thanks a ton you saved my day.